# Running multiple test classes with maven surefire plugin

Tags: java, maven, junit, concurrency, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to use the parallel option in the maven-surefire-plugin to run multiple test classes at once. Below is my configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m</argLine>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>**/Test*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
    <runOrder>hourly</runOrder>
    <parallel>classes</parallel>
    <threadCountClasses>5</threadCountClasses>
</configuration>
```

It very clearly is doing parallel test classes but it's doing far more than what I would expect. I see it jumping up to approximately 40 test classes being executed at once, despite the threadCountClasses being set to 5. Am I misunderstanding how these options work? My desire would be for only five test classes to be executing at any one time. As it is, it's choking my system with 40.

I'm currently running version **2.17** of the plugin.

**Edit**: Is there any chance the number of CPU cores would come into play here? After more careful accounting, I realize I am running exactly 40 test classes with this configuration and I have 8 cores. It seems like it would be quite a coincidence if the CPU cores don't play a part.

Comment: If you run the tests with 1 thread, does it kickoff exactly 8 test classes?  That could pretty clearly point to the number of CPU cores being a factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per official documentation on the [`threadCountClasses`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#threadCountClasses) configuration entry

> This attribute allows you to specify the concurrency in test classes, i.e.:
>
> - number of concurrent classes if `threadCount` is 0 or unspecified
> - limited classes concurrency if `useUnlimitedThreads` is set to `true`
> - if `threadCount` and certain thread-count parameters are > 0 for parallel, the concurrency is computed from ratio. For instance `parallel`=`all` and the ratio between `threadCountSuites`:`threadCountClasses`:`threadCountMethods` is 2:3:5, there is 30% of threadCount in concurrent classes.
> - as in the previous case but without this leaf thread-count. Example: `parallel`=`suitesAndClasses`, `threadCount`=16, `threadCountSuites`=5, threadCountClasses is unspecified leaf, the number of concurrent classes is varying from >= 11 to 14 or 15. The `threadCountSuites` become number of threads.
>
> Only makes sense to use in conjunction with the parallel parameter. The default value 0 behaves same as unspecified one.

In your case you are not specifying the `threadCount` element, hence you should fall into the first case (number of concurrent classes) which however it doesn't seem to be the case.

The third and fourth case instead define a ratio (and not a specific number), as it instead seems to happen in your case. Ratio however depends on your test classes (suites, if any, classes and methods) and not on your CPU cores.

However, the [`perCoreThreadCount`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#perCoreThreadCount) configuration entry:

> Indicates that `threadCount`, `threadCountSuites`, `threadCountClasses`, `threadCountMethods` are per cpu core.

Is set to `true` by default, effectively influencing the dynamics described above and matching the behavior you described (according to option one above).

Hence, a suggestion would be to set it to `false`.

Comment: Excellent explanation. I definitely missed that part about the per cpu core.